# How do you create a stutter edit?

Tags: how-to

Linkin Park, BT, etc., each have their own signature stutter edit from time to time.

I would like to incorporate something like this into a robot voice I have to create (sort of like an Eagle-Eye voice giving directions).

Are there any rules of thumb or "must do"s to achieve an edit like these? A particular type of fade? A length of copying? I know BT released or will release an Izotope plug-in which creates these - however, that's lower on the totem pole of purchases I will be making in the near future. And, I'm versed in Pro Tools, so it should be pretty easy to figure out how to do... Right?

One thing I found when playing around, is that if you take a sound or effect, duplicate a chunk of say 10 milliseconds over and over about 50 times, then take half of that (5 milliseconds), then half of that again, and again, it will create a great digital computer noise which rises in pitch (because the cycles are getting shorter, I guess).

Thanks for any tips you care to share on this subject.

Answer (score 5):

I do the sampler-loop-length-param automation trick John mentioned, usually.

For a different sound - as others have said, there are many flavors of this - or for a starter approach/easy way to generate some basic stuff, you can always use the excellent and free Buffer Override (stellar, must-have) or SupaTrigga (basic but great) plug-ins. Doing this THEN doing other stutter effects with the results printed to a track gets pretty fun.

If you wanna get *really* extreme, download GleetchLab...you may need some shrooms to grok the interface, though.

Comment: Dude! +1 for the mighty-incredible-yet-hard-to-fathom-interface GleetchLab. Very strange program, and yet I keep coming back to it…

Answer (score 5):

Just got the announcement of this in my inbox:

[iZotope's Stutter Edit](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/stutteredit/)

Comment: I had that too! lol checking out the video to it now...

Comment: ..and now downloading the demo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Usually, these effects are done in a sampler, like Kontakt, where you can modulate the loop length with a control parameter. This way, you take a long loop and make it only a 16th note long, for instance with the mod wheel.

Comment: That's the method I use!

Answer (score 3):

A buffer override is the typical way to get those sounds, like noise jockey mentioned. There are a couple free tools that compact glitch processing together.

Try these,

http://illformed.org/plugins/glitch/

http://www.gleetchplug.com/gleetchplug/Main.html

http://destroyfx.smartelectronix.com/

And, if you have the time and the know how, do what Aphex twin and Squarepusher do, learn supercollider!  (lol)

http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

The best rule of thumb copy and pasting is to make your selection start and finish at the zero crossing.

You can zoom right in and copy at the single cycle levels to create buzzy effects like BT. Or copy a few cycles.

This kind of work is better done in an audio editor (Soundtrack Pro, Peak, Amadeus, etc) rather than a DAW. Just use your copy paste short cuts and go crazy.

-=-

The first assignment in my senior electroacoustic composition class was to compose a piece using just a mono recording of your voice, zero effects, only copy and paste. No chunk could be longer than a phoneme. That definitely gets you intimate with zoomed in digital audio!

Comment: some DAWs do extend selection to zero crossings..

Answer (score 1):

If using Pro Tools, try Elastic time. The "rhythmic" mode produces some very interesting results when pushed beyond its normal parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The big trick to making great stutters is the rhythm. The best stutters in my opinion are rhythmic and varies. Figure out a rhythm/tempo and slice it that way. Then play around by omitting a sample or two to create a rhythmic variation. Much like a stutter in the stutter. Or a glitch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the stutter effect in Logic Pro, then I really recommend having a quick look at this tutorial by SF Logic Ninja. He shows how to get a really effective stutter on a drumbeat, but the same technique can be applied to other sounds:

http://www.youtube.com/user/SFLogicNinja#p/u/53/xAIX-M0NEVQ

Answer (score 1):

OpenAV's [Masha](http://openavproductions.com/artyfx/) plugin (LV2) does this - you set the rate, and when it's turned on it it stutters what ever audio is fed into it:

> Masha is a beat grinder plugin: it records a segement of audio and plays it back as a loop, causing a “stutter” effect. The controls are:
>
> - Volume
> - PassThru
> - Time
>
> Volume changes the loudness of the stutter-loop. PassThru allows bleeding the normal signal trough. Time is a BPM dependant control that changes the loop-record and playback length. Gradually reduce this value to get that standard DJ stutter effect!

Answer (score 0):

Take a speech track from anywhere and then speed it up and use it as a side chain on a noise gate or expander affecting the track that you want to stutter.

Try different combinations of unrelated speech with a kick or snare track as triggers if you want it more rhythmic.