# How is this sound made?

Tags: effect

I have a base idea but wanted to get your feedback.

It's the skipping, chopped sound in movies like Starwars, Batman and Transformers.

Listen here at 2:08 for example.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZicrp_p4BE

What is your take on it?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like they do it on all of the big tire-squeals.

Comment: 'why' would be a far more interesting question

Comment: Amen, Tim. I've noticed that stutter effect on all sorts of stuff recently, from the tires to big robots to alien voices...it's like the gated reverb of 2010-11 sound design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a stutter edit?](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/how-do-you-create-a-stutter-edit)

Answer (score 3):

[How do you create a stutter edit?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/how-do-you-create-a-stutter-edit)

Comment: Wow. I asked that question last year!!! Time flies.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can accomplish this with LFO(s), probably with square wave shapes, modulating volume and any number of other parameters.  For extra fun, assign one modulator to another modulator's rate in order to speed up and slow down the effect.

Comment: Hey Nick, I didn't know you posted here. Good to see you. Nick has some of the best sound tutorials on the net. Peace - Mark

Comment: Hello Nick. You do have great tutorials

Answer (score 1):

Mark, this is just an animal vocal processed with a LFO applied to the amplitude. In Batman, it sounds like a young bear, probably a panda.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my try at it. Using a free panda roar sample (8bit). Layered 2 Samplers with a Left to right panorama and LFO Triangle wav modulating volume. Then a third duplicate of Sampler but this time used a synth pad. Bounced it all down to one audio clip, then sliced up and changed pitches.

Result:

http://www.abletondaily.com/sounds/panda_studder.wav

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the tutorial on that - I've got a client asking for exactly this kind of thing. For anyone else in a similar position, Mark's tutorial on this can be found right here:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa44-iPjwCg&feature=plcp

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't normally reply to "how do I make this sound" posts (there are countless tutorial online and I have limited time), but as you sent me PM I thought you might need some additional pointers.  (I figured you must be keen to have PM me.)  As others have pointed out to you the stutter can be easily created by using an LFO to modulate the output amplifier.  (Look at tutorials for creating Transformers sounds and you'll get the idea.)  This effect can then be applied to any base sound.  In the case of the Batman wheel screech I suggest mixing a couple of sawtooths together and then cut the low-end with HP filter.  You want lots of high-end as you are trying to replicate the squeal of a tyre skipping across the road.  You may also want to add some modulation to the filters cut-off.

By the way, in my opinion I think this sound could be improved by layering it with a real tyre squeal.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. An LFO was the first thing I thought. Its as simple as that I guess. I think the initial sound secret lies in the source. The bear and panda roar is brilliant, never would of thought of that. I'm going to make a tutorial soon on this. Thanks again, Mark

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend a useful vsti for making stutter effects. Check [dfx Skidder](http://destroyfx.smartelectronix.com/), it's really good.